# BoxOAuthException invalid_grant Current date\/time MUST be before the expiration date\/time listed in the 'exp' claim"

Tags: box

I just got this error while trying to do OAuth with Box.com.

```
BoxOAuthException: 
Message: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Current date\/time MUST be before the expiration date\/time listed in the 'exp' claim"}
```

Wondering if I have a time sync problem with my server. Maybe my server's network time is out of sync or something.

Anyone ever see this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This error happens when the Unix time on your local machine and the Box server are out of sync. " - via Murtza

https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Getting-Please-check-the-exp-claim-Exception/m-p/23843/highlight/true#M969